# Static IP behind a switch not routing to other subnet

Tags: routing, dhcp

Consider two scenarios:

1. Scenario 1: Cisco SG200-26 -> 5-port Hub -> *Test Machine*
2. Scenario 2: Cisco SG200-26 -> *Test Machine*

I have a device 192.168.2.1 connected directly to the Cisco SG200-26 acting as DHCP giving out IP addresses for his own subnet (192.168.2.XXX). I'm trying to set my *Test Machine* to a static IP on subnet 192.168.1.XXX.

In scenario 1, when I set my *Test Machine* to DHCP, it successfully receives a 192.168.2.XXX IP but cannot access 192.168.1.XXX subnet at all, and setting it with a static IP 192.168.1.XXX conversely doesn't allow it to route to the 192.168.2.XXX subnet at all.

In scenario 2 however, whether I set my *Test machine* to DHCP (192.168.2.XXX) or static (192.168.1.XXX), in both cases, both subnets are routable.

What am I missing in scenario 1 to have the static 192.168.1.XXX IP address route properly to the 192.168.2.XXX subnet as well ?

Comment: You really need to provide more information. You left out the router. You should edit your question to include the router (which is what routes between the networks) and the configurations of the router and switches.

Comment: what is the default gateway on the test machine?

Comment: You should provide a network diagram to get a better understanding

Comment: It is a more general question than that... Just wondering if the DHCP traffic is supposed to work in Scenario 1 as it works in Scenario 2.

Comment: It depends on the information the DHCP server is sending.  What is the default gateway for the Test machine?

Comment: Is the test machine in scenario 1 the same machine as in scenario 2?
Is the machine in scenario 2 connected to the same port that the hub was connected to in scenario 1?
If not, are the 2 ports in the same vlan?
In which vlan is the port that the 192.168.2.1 device is connected to?

When you say "both subnets are routable" I assume you mean reachable? How are you testing this?

As was already asked 2 months ago: can we have a network diagram, is there a router in the network, what options is the DHCP server sending, which default gateway is configured on the test machine?

Comment: Since the bounty was awarded to Zack Scaringello'd answer, can the OP (or anyone) please clarify how scenario 2 could have been working ok if there was no inter-vlan routing? Was the subnet mask /16 and were the ports in scenario 1 in different vlans but in the same vlan in scenario 2? That's really the only explanation I can think of, so I'd  love to hear what I might be missing...

Comment: I think it's because the SG200 doesn't think two subnets could be reachable through the same port because it expects a single device in each port and not a hub that can lead to more than one device on different subnets. I don't know if this is by design or just particular implementation.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Just wondering if the DHCP traffic is supposed to work in Scenario 1 as it works in Scenario 2

Yes, the hub should be transparent as far as DHCP is concerned so assuming the ports in both scenarios are in the same vlan, the behaviour should be exactly the same (assuming test machine is the only device connected to the hub).

So if you see different behaviour in scenario 1 and 2 and you want us to help to explain why, you will need to answer our questions for more information.

[edit: moved follow-up questions to comments]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I will have to dig in those details and get back to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use the Answer section to ask questions.  If you need clarification, please use the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Posting your configuration would be quite helpful.

Most likely you need to enable inter-vlan routing and create an SVI for both VLANs.

Once they have a layer 3 interface to route through you should be able to talk between VLANs just fine.

I am not familiar with that particular switch, but for most IOS devices inter-vlan routing is enabled by default and all you will need to do is create the SVIs (for both 192.168.1.X and 192.168.2.X)

Comment: I don't understand how this could be the correct answer; if there was no inter-vlan routing then how could scenario 2 have worked ok ?

Answer (score 1):

DHCP (Server) options typically include default gateway and DNS server at a minimum.  The default gateway option should specify the router/gateway IP address for the subnet.

Typically, each VLAN carries traffic for a unique subnet and a layer3 device does inter-VLAN routing.  To forward/direct DHCP request from a subnet to a DHCP server on a different subnet, you need to configure that to happen.  In Cisco IOS, it is called an `ip helper address` and is applied to the layer3 interface for the VLAN(s) that the DHCP server(subnet) is not on.